# Upgrading Doctrine from 2.0.6 to 2.3

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to upgrade the Doctrine library in my Zend application from version 2.0.6 to 2.3. I assumed this would just involve copying the over the newer library files over the existing library - provided there are no major changes which would require me to change my application code.

However, I downloaded a zip from their [GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/2.3.4) page and found that the directories in the 2.3 differ greatly to the Doctrine version I currently have installed (consists of Common, DBAL, ORM and Symfony folders whereas 2.3 is completely different). I can't find anything on the difference in these folders, maybe I'm just really slow.

In my existing set up, I am not using any third party libraries to integrate Doctrine, most of it is done through autoloading in Bootstrap.php.

After several unsuccessful attempts to upgrade the Doctrine library, I decided to follow this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-doctrine-php-zend/) based on the assumption that it will handle the unfamiliar directory structure of the Doctrine I downloaded. However further down the page this tutorial also refers to the Doctrine library as having the four folders that I have in my existing set up, which doesn't match the newer version of Doctrine.

Would sincerely appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or tell me where I am going wrong.

ps I am using Zend 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three ways:

1. Use [composer](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#setup-project).
2. You can use [Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/2.3.4) as Git Submodule. You'll get only Doctrine\ORM. Other libraries you get through its Submodules.
3. Download all the libraries separately: [Doctrine\ORM](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/2.3.4), [Doctrine\Common](https://github.com/doctrine/common/tree/2.3.0), [Doctrine\DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/tree/2.3.4), [Symfony\Component\Console](https://github.com/symfony/Console/tree/v2.3.1), [Symfony\Component\Yaml](https://github.com/symfony/Yaml/tree/v2.3.1)